# What to do with 'duplicate' apps? (ie. HTC version and 'vanilla' version)

Tags: applications, htc, bloatware

I was going through my app list today when I saw:

> Facebook
>
> Facebook for HTC Sense

similarly, there are other "duplicate" apps like Peep & Twitter, Mail & Gmail, Calendar (red) & Calendar (blue).

At the moment, with an un-rooted phone I believe I can only remove the non-HTC versions. However if I root my phone, I should be able to remove the HTC versions if I want.

I was wondering though, what would happen if I remove the HTC versions of the apps? Will it mean HTC-integrated apps like friend stream will stop working?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running sense that comes with these "extra" "sense like experience" apps.

You are right, you cannot remove them by normal means. If you go to manage applications and select each htc app (Peep, facebook for htc sense) you will not be given the option to uninstall them or delete them.

If you do root your phone, you will be able to uninstall them via either adb or flashing some zips. You won't be able to just uninstall them the normal way once rooted.

Removing peep can possibly disrupt some htc widgets but you can still access twitter via the twitter app or other apps such as plume, tweetdeck etc.
Same thing for facebook/facebook for htc sense.

Friend stream is another htc app that integrates other social apps. Users report different compatibility issues between Friend stream and versions of the social apps. It does allow login with any version of facebook/twitter/flickr.

Comment: so just to clarify, so it is still possible for some HTC apps to work even after removing the htc sense versions and leaving the 'normal' versions of the apps?

Comment: No the HTC versions won't work with the non-HTC versions of the apps.